# How to check that given polynomials form a Groebner basis

Tags: polynomials, ideals, groebner-basis

I am wondering if some polynomials are given, how do we know whether they form Groebner basis or not.
Note that it is not necessary that given poly's form a reduced Groebner basis.

I know how to find a Grobner basis of an ideal but Grobner basis is not unique. So I don't know how to determine if they are Groebner basis.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a variant of [Buchberger's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buchberger%27s_algorithm) to check if a given set of generators is a Gröbner basis.  Specifically:

1. For each pair of generators, compute the $S$-polynomial.
2. Use the [multivariate division algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_division_algorithm) to reduce the $S$-polynomial with respect to the generators as much as possible.
3. If the remainder is zero for every possible $S$-polynomial, then the generating set is a Gröbner basis.

Comment: Thanks, Jim. But I am still confused. This method guarantees the set is a Groebner basis but how do I know this set generates the given ideal. For example, we have $I=\langle x^2y^2\rangle$ and the given set is $\{x,y\}$. $\{x,y\}$ satisfies all the three conditions above. But it's not the Groebner basis for $I$. Can you help me?

Comment: @Falang If you _have_ a generating set for an ideal, you can use Buchberger's algorithm to find a Gröbner basis for that ideal.  If you are given a 2nd Gröbner basis, you can check whether the ideals that they generate are the same using the multivariate division algorithm.  Just check that each of the generators for each ideal is an element of the other ideal.